# Wpf Binding двух строковых значений без XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Как правильно забиндеть два значения и слеш между ними одному textBox, который генерируется силами C# без XAML?

Вот такой исходник:

```
            var coolEdit = new EditControl {IsReadOnly= true};


            var coolTextBox = new TextBox
            {
                IsReadOnly = true,
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right
            };


            var pathCoolBinding= "DataMas[" + i + "].Data1+\\+DataMas[" + i + "].Data2" ;
            var coolBinding = new Binding(pathCoolBinding);
            coolBinding.Source = coolViewModel;
            coolBinding.StringFormat = "n6";
            coolTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, coolBinding);
            
            coolEdit.Content = coolTextBox;
```

Но при таком раскладе я вижу пустое поле, хоть программа не падает. Возможно ли вообще такое ? pls help

Comment: А почему вы вообще это делаете минуя XAML?

Comment: Этот момент происходит в цикле , так как таких генерирующихся кусочков интерфейса не определенно изначально

Comment: Ну так для этого есть решения в XAML. Никто не использует c# код для генерации XAML, задумайтесь об этом)

Comment: Если есть для xaml, возможно есть для  C#. Тем более таких вьюшек у нас очень много и каждому прописывать одно и то же? Не круто.

Comment: Для этого тоже есть решения в XAML UserControl зовется...

Comment: Меня больше интересует как такое чудо забиндеть используя C#, а не XAML  )

Comment: `как такое чудо` - скорей "такой костыль", ну, дело ваше, потом не жалуйтесь что приложение лагает и работает как-то не так.

Comment: @Shadow вы просите реализовать для вас bad practice - ваш подход неправильный, и в WPF все далется намного проще. А не работает у вас, потому что `Binding` может привязываться только к свойствам `public SomeType DataMas { get; set; }`, а у вас скорее всего поле, но вы к сожалению, оставили этот момент секретным. К тому же `DataContext` должен быть установлен на тот класс, где этот `DataMas` находится.

Comment: Если покажете ваш класс данных, и расскажете, какую задачу решаете, возможно я смогу показать вам, как это легко и просто сделать в XAML. Пока по вашему кусочку кода не понятно, что именно происходит.

Comment: @aepot 1)по отдельности эти компоненты успешно билдяться и выводяться в текстбоксе. Они открыты уже..2) Вариант с Xaml отсекается , так как тут очень много легаси кода, который делался до меня. И вот конкретно этот момент - был без Xaml. Переделывать всю эту громадину - смысла и времени нет..3) задача проста и не тривиальна:забиндеть два поля массива к этому элементу и просто между ними оставить слеш. Возможно ли это вообще сделать?

Comment: 1) Можно в класс данных добавить `public override ToString() => Data1 + " / " + Data2;`, и просто прибиндиться к `DataMas[i]`. 2) Можно использовать [`MultiBinding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=netframework-4.8) и [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8) 3) Можно прибиндиться опять же к `DataMas[i]` и использовать [`IValueConverter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Как видите, ваша задача проста, и ее можно релизовать множеством способов. Если вариант с `ToString()` вам не подходит, можете еще 4) Добавить свойство `public string Data3 => Data1 + " / " + Data2;` и прибиндиться к `DataMas[i].Data3`.

Comment: По-хорошему, у вас огромный технический долг, и если эту "громадину" переписать на номальный XAML с MVVM, она похудеет раза в 3. Судя по проблеме, писалось приложение скорее всего людьми, которые не совсем понимали, как устроен WPF.

Comment: @aepot Покажите пожалуйста второй вариант, так как у меня оно не билдилось

Comment: @Shadow я не могу вам показать ни один из вариантов, потому что я без понятия, как построить `Binding` в C#, я использую XAML. Попробуйте 4 вариант. Как по мне, он должен быть самым простым для вас, судя по тому, что вы сказали, что свойства по отдельности биндятся нормально.